# Displaying specific data from mySQL using sessions IDs

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to display the users first name after they login. They login using their email and password. Though, I would like to collect their first name and display it. Their name is in the same table that the email/password are in. Traditionally, I would use a session ID like this below.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['first'] =  $first; 
?>
```

But this typically is for submitted data in a form and is used after the form has been authenticated. My question is, how would I gather data from the mySQl table rather than collecting it from the form and be able to have it has a session ID?... if that makes sense

Comment: Post the script that they login with

Comment: Here's my login code http://jsfiddle.net/tKNbE/

Comment: Complete working answer below :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Select the first name (and any other fields you desire) when checking the user name and password match.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

$sql=sprintf("SELECT email, firstname FROM users WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", 
              $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"]);

//You'd better use parameterized query

$result = mysqli->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if(mysqli->num_rows > 0)
{
    $_SESSION["email"] = $row["email"];
    $_SESSION["firstname"] = $row["firstname"]; 
}
else 
{
 //operation for no matches
}
```

Comment: Would I append this before the login action? Here's my login code http://jsfiddle.net/tKNbE/

Comment: I have seen PHP code on jsfiddle for the first time. Congratulations. Then just add your fields you want to select right after `SELECT id, ...` By the way, you may use PHP fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In your script where they login...just fetch the row and store into session...

Im using PDO, because thats much safer than the deprecated mysql_* functions you use in your login example.....

```
//start the session
session_start();

//Get their credentials, as follows...
$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = md5($_POST['password']);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username=? AND password=?");
$stmt->execute(array($name, $pass));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row > 0 ) {
  //Store users info in a session
   $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
   $_SESSION["firstname"] = $row["firstname"]; 
   $_SESSION["auth"] = "set";
  //Redirect to the user area, where you can echo their name
   header ("Location: /app");
  //Once in the user area, you can just echo their name like so...
  //echo "Hello ".$_SESSION['username'].", Welcome to my site";

} else {
 //Redirect back to login if their info is incorrect
 header('location: /login');
 //whatever your login page name might be...
}
```

But heres the code, if you don't wanna bother changing your site to utilizing PDO...

```
   include("db.php");
   session_start();
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
   {
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $password=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $sql="SELECT id, username, firstname FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and passcode='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if(count($row)>0)
    {
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 'set';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
    header ("Location: /app");
    }
    else
    {
    $error="Your Hngout credentials are incorrect"; 
    }
   }
```